# bogus auto-unlock from launcher after crash

Tags: 15.04

After a system crash (not full, just one that triggers the ubuntu bug report popup), I always get ALL my app icons unlocked from Launcher so when I close apps, suddenly their icon disappears. Is that a known bug or a setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: use the terminal to (re)set the launcher icons after a crash. The locked launcher icons are stored in gconf at `com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites`, which you can access with `dconf` or terminal.

This gets the current value:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

Save the output of the above, then after a crash, run this:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "$value"
```

For example:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['application://nautilus.desktop', 'application://firefox.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'unity://devices']"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to accept this though (fortunately) did not have the chance to test it yet.